# Permanent Alt-Tab error causes me to force restart on Laptop

Tags: windows-7, alt-tab

Ok, I have a problem with my Alt-Tab in windows 7 on my Dell XPS Laptop. Whenever I use Alt-Tab the bar that comes up with all the options to select doesn't go away and I cannot select any of the options.

On top of that I can't even try and get rid of it, it is permanent and overrides everything. I've tried completely factory finishing my Laptop and on top of that I've installing all new drivers and its getting extremely annoying since anytime I hit Alt-Tab I pretty much have to restart my laptop cause it becomes completely frozen in alt-tab and cannot select anything to get rid of it. Any Ideas?

Comment: As a workaround, you can use Win+Tab, or Alt+Esc instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing any of the optional updates windows has, mostly those updates have fixes for these kind of problems.